# control text align and float in iframe (same domain)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe with a width with text inside and I want to align this text on the right hand side of the iframe. Iframe's src is on the same domain. Is it possible to do using JavaScript, and if so, how??

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can call create a javascript function for the page displayed inside the iframe that set the position of the text.  Then you can call that function from outside the iframe

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.setTextToRightHandSide();
```

inside html can look like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>inside html</title>
    <script>
        function setTextToRightHandSide() {
            var div = document.getElementById('textBlock');

            div.style.position = "absolute";
            div.style.right = "0px";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="textBlock">some text here</div>
</body>
</html>
```